# Excluding child elements in xpath expression

Tags: java, xml, xpath

HI have the following xml.

```
<filters>
    <filter>
        <field>
            <name>empId</name>
            <type>int</type>
        </field>
        <op>in</op>
        <value>eID</value>
        <valueType>PERI</valueType>
    </filter>
    <filter>
        <field>
            <name>desc</name>
            <type>string</type>
        </field>
        <op>in</op>
        <value>dbDesc</value>
        <valueType>PERI</valueType>
    </filter>
</filters>
```

I want to retrieve only "name" element, "op" and "value" elements. Iam using the below xpath expresssion. but unable to exclude the "type" nodes which are under "field" element.

`//filter//*[not(self::valueType)] and [not(following-sibling::type)]//text()`

My output should be:

```
empId
in
eID
desc
in
dbDesc
```

Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The following XPath expression will select the text from all `name`, `op`, or `value` elements:**

```
(//name|//op|//value)/text()
```

### Update per OP request in the comments:

> I want name, op, value only from the filters element.

**Adjust the XPath similar to as you mention in your comment:**

```
(//filters//name|//filters//op|//filters//value)/text()
```

**Or, more efficiently (provided tightening it up doesn't lose any matches in your general case):**

```
(/filters/filter/field/name|/filters/filter/op|/filters/filter/value)/text()
```

Comment: That is working fine but the problem is it is returning other name elements which are at the top of the xml. I have a big xml file I have posted a small part of my xml in the question. I want name, op, value only from the filters element.

Comment: I have added //filters//name in place of //name. seems working.

Comment: @MaheshVarma If the XML structures are statically known, you could also use `//filter/field/name`. Some processors do not optimize expressions well that contain many `//` steps.

Comment: @MathiasMüller I am not sure, they may change the xml structure but the elements may change their places.

Comment: @MaheshVarma Then `//filters//name` is fine.

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

`//filter//*[self::name or self::op or self::value]/text()`